# Can't get root passworldless ssh to work

Tags: 16.04, ssh, root

I have master and slave machines and wish to be able to passwordless ssh between root accounts.

On slave I did `sudo su - root` and `passwd` to set up a root password.

On slave I edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added `PermitRootLogin yes`

Doing this allowed me to do the following on master:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_root
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_root.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_root
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_root.pub
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_root.pub  root@slave
```

But when I now try `ssh root@slave` it always asks for a password and then allows login.

I have tried on slave editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and changing `PermitRootLogin yes`to `PermitRootLogin without-password` but then  `ssh root@slave` gives `Permission denied`.

Tearing my hair out, any help is much appreciated!

PS: I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and I login to root on master to do connect to slave using `sudo su - root` but I did the stuff on slave as a different user (maybe that makes a difference?)

EDIT: I've added the output of `ssh -v root@slave2` might help?

```
root@master:~# ssh -v root@slave2
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to slave2 [192.168.1.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH* compat 
x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to slave2:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
HA256:D8gzBgBFRg1AnBsKfrY/fVGzIXDPtA+86TZa3e7Ylms
debug1: Host 'slave2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Since you've used a non-standard name for the key file (`id_rsa_root` instead of plain `id_rsa`) you will probably need to give it explicitly on the ssh command line i.e. `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_root root@slave`. As a side note, if you are doing passwordless ssh you should **not** need to set root's password and you should use `PermitRootLogin without-password` rather than `PermitRootLogin yes`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!! Do you want to answer it and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've used a non-standard name for the key file (`id_rsa_root` instead of plain `id_rsa`) you will need to give it explicitly on the ssh command line i.e.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_root root@slave
```

Alternatively, you could set up a `~/.ssh/config` file containing an entry for `slave` with the appropriate `IdentityFile` entry. See `man ssh_config` for details.

---

As a side note, if you are doing passwordless ssh you should **not** need to set root's login password (although not doing so initially means you will need to manually copy the public key to root's `authorized_keys` file, using `sudo`, since you won't be able to use `ssh-copy-id`) and you should use `PermitRootLogin without-password` rather than `PermitRootLogin yes` in the remote system's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.